# Elliptic operators with Robin boundary conditions

Tags: matrices, elliptic-pde

Can it be proved that two elliptic operators with Robin boundary conditions generate an interval $P$-matrix?

$$
-a\Delta u_i = f_i, \quad a\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial n} + bu_i = 0
$$
$$
-a\Delta v_i = f_i, \quad a\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial n} + cv_i = 0
$$

Here, $f_i \geq 0$ are linear independent functions, $0 < b \leq c$, so $0 \leq v_i \leq u_i$.

Let $B_{ji} = (f_j, u_i)$, $C_{ji} = (f_j, v_i)$, and $C_{ji} \leq A_{ji} \leq B_{ji}$.

It is true that $A$ is always a $P$-matrix?